# Not able to create Specflow Feature File in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, testing

I am using Selenium for the first time ever in order to run some automated UI tests.  Unfortunately, I have come across a bump in the road. I am trying to create a Specflow Feauture File. In this [tutorial](https://blog.novanet.no/writing-your-first-ui-test/), it says that under my features folder, I should add a new item and then select "SpecFlow Feature file" and it will be created.  When I try to add a new item, that option does not appear. Can somebody tell me what I may be doing wrong or why it is not working?

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the "Specflow plugin"? If not, then you aren't going to get the option. Maybe try looking at the installation and Setup instructions for "Specflow" with Visual Studio, here: (https://specflow.org/getting-started/)

Comment: I did, through manage NUget packages.

Comment: Check this one out then: (https://specflow.org/documentation/Troubleshooting-Visual-Studio-Integration/) - Look under the subtitle `Unable to find plugin in the plugin search path: SpecRun when saving / generating feature files`

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you used was done in 2017. Can you look at this one?

https://specflow.org/getting-started/

1. Make sure you are updated to current versions of everything.
2. Only use one test runner in your nuget package, ie NUnit, MSTest,
   SpecRun
3. Also Click Extensions > Manage Extensions and search
   SpecFlow. Install SpecFlow for Visual Studio.